# Как оформить вставку "барабанная дробь"?

Tags: вставка

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно оформить предложение так: "А теперь %барабанная дробь% мы перейдем к самому главному" или же: "А теперь - барабанная дробь! - мы перейдем к самому главному"? Я понимаю, что текст несерьезный, несколько шутливый, но все-таки, как правильно оформлять подобное? Спасибо.
P.S. Вместо знака % - стоят звездочки. При постановке звездочек,  фраза просто трансформировалась в курсив. Пришлось оформить процентами.

Answer (score 3):

А теперь (барабанная дробь!) мы перейдем к самому главному!

Оформление по принципу ремарки в пьесах.

Comment: Спасибо. Такой вариант, если честно, и не пришел мне в голову. Спасибо. Раньше я встречала на просторах интернета варианты со звездочками. Но по правилам звездочек же и не бывает в текстах (если это только не сноска). Поэтому я решила, что надо оформлять как вставку, через тире. А про вариант со скобками и не думала.

Comment: Анна, звездочки на всякие интернет-форумах используются для графического выделения текста, но не пунктуационного.

Comment: Нет, я говорю именно о вариантах вроде: "О чем ты вообще говоришь? %вращаю глазами%" или там: "Неужели он так и сказал?! %присела%" Опять же - ставлю проценты, т.к. звездочки просто превращают текст в курсив.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что "барабанная дробь" в данных предложениях будет не вводной, а вставной конструкцией. Принципиальное отличие первой конструкции от второй в том, что вводные слова, обороты и конструкции, хотя синтаксически и не связаны с остальными членами предложения, но чаще всего обозначают отношение говорящего к тому, что он сообщает. Вставная конструкция настолько "синтаксически" свободна, что не только не подлежит никакой систематизации или структурированию (и, конечно, может быть удалена без ущерба для грамматического смысла), но и обозначает "действие, происходящее за кадром".  Выделяться вставные конструкции могут и тире, и скобками. Кстати тире и скобки обозначают паузу большей длительности, чем запятая.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ. Но я в комментарии и указывала, что речь идет о вставке, а не о вводной конструкции. Я знаю, что это вставка. Меня интересовало оформление в данном случае. Как лучше оформить. Как правильней.